# Can I use a formula field as the key of a map?

Tags: formula-field, map

Can I use a formula field as the key of a map??

```
ABCMap.put(cc.Country__c+SPLIT_DASH+cc.month__c+ groupMatchSet.get(cc.group__c) , 0.0 );
```

Here , Country__c is a formula field.

Getting the following error :
Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Country__c for SObject CWV__c at line 386 column 155

Comment: Please show the code related to "cc" instance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. In Apex, valid formula fields will not throw "Invalid field" compile errors. The most likely cause here is that Country__c is not the actual API name of the field you want on the object "CWV__c". Check your schema.

There are rare cases where you may get compile errors from a valid field if the API version of the class you're compiling pre-dates the introduction of a standard field, or (I think) if the field type was introduced after the target API version (Lat/Long standard geolocation fields come to mind but I'm also not 100% sure if those would give the same error in that particular case). I doubt that is the case in your example... the most likely cause I'd bet on would be that the API name of the field you're targeting is not actually "Country__c".